# How can I make dynamically generated fields in flutter_form_bloc?

Tags: forms, flutter, bloc

I already have most of the forms done but I need to be able to generate fields based on another field in this case, a checkbox group. Depending on how many boxes the user checks, I need to be able to generate twice as many fields (two for each checkbox). Is there any efficient way to do that?

As you can see, my current setup of start time and end time variables isn't the best. It would be great if I could generate them. Should I use a list? Also, how could I listen to the value in `flutter_form_bloc`? The value I need is `scheduleDaysField` as you could probably tell by the items in it. So if the user selects Monday and Friday, then I need to generate four fields, Monday start and end time and Friday start and end time.

Here's my current setup:

```
class AddScheduleFormBloc extends FormBloc<String, dynamic> {
  AddScheduleFormBloc() : super(isLoading: true);

  // ignore: close_sinks
  final subjectField = SelectFieldBloc(
    validators: [FieldBlocValidators.requiredSelectFieldBloc],
  );

  // ignore: close_sinks
  final scheduleDaysField = MultiSelectFieldBloc(
    validators: [FieldBlocValidators.requiredMultiSelectFieldBloc],
    items: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
  );

  // ignore: close_sinks
  final sameTimeEveryday = BooleanFieldBloc(initialValue: false);

  // ignore: close_sinks
  final mondayStartTime = InputFieldBloc();
  // ignore: close_sinks
  final tuesdayStartTime = InputFieldBloc();
  // ignore: close_sinks
  final wednesdayStartTime = InputFieldBloc();
  // ignore: close_sinks
  final thursdayStartTime = InputFieldBloc();
  // ignore: close_sinks
  final fridayStartTime = InputFieldBloc();

  // ignore: close_sinks
  final mondayEndTime = InputFieldBloc();
  // ignore: close_sinks
  final tuesdayEndTime = InputFieldBloc();
  // ignore: close_sinks
  final wednesdayEndTime = InputFieldBloc();
  // ignore: close_sinks
  final thursdayEndTime = InputFieldBloc();
  // ignore: close_sinks
  final fridayEndTime = InputFieldBloc();

  @override
  List<FieldBloc> get fieldBlocs => [
        subjectField,
        scheduleDaysField,
        sameTimeEveryday,
        // all the other fields
      ];

  @override
  Stream<FormBlocState<String, dynamic>> onLoading() async* {
    yield* _setSubjectFieldValues();
  }

  @override
  Stream<FormBlocState<String, dynamic>> onReload() async* {
    yield* _setSubjectFieldValues();
  }

  @override
  Stream<FormBlocState<String, dynamic>> onSubmitting() async* {
    // TODO: onSubmitting()
    yield state.toSuccess();
  }

  Stream<FormBlocState<String, dynamic>> _setSubjectFieldValues() async* {
    List<Subject> subjects = SubjectsRepository.getAllSubjects();
    for (Subject subject in subjects) {
      subjectField.addItem(subject.name);
    }
    subjectField.updateInitialValue(subjects.first.name);
    yield state.toLoaded();
  }
}
```